# German Phone Number Regex

Tags: regex, numbers

I have a regex
`\(?\+\(?49?\)?[ ()]?([- ()]?\d[- ()]?){11}`

This correctly matches German phone code like

1. +491739341284
2. +49 1739341284
3. (+49) 1739341284
4. +49 17 39 34 12 84
5. +49 (1739) 34 12 84
6. +(49) (1739) 34 12 84
7. +49 (1739) 34-12-84

but fails to match **0049 (1739) 34-12-84**.
I need to adjust the regular expression so that it can match numbers with **0049** as well. can anyone help me with the regex?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How much of the REGEx you have do you understand? What could be the problem?

Comment: so I tried this basic ```((\+49)?(0049)?)([0-9]{11})```, but it wont removed the spaces, so stack overflow it and got ```\(?\+\(?49?\)?[ ()]?([- ()]?\d[- ()]?){11}``` this one, now I'm finding it hard to add (0049) thing in this one

Comment: tried this ```\(?\+\(?49?(0049)?[ ()]?([- ()]?\d[- ()]?){11}``` but didn't worked

Comment: Note that your pattern does not match `+(49) (1739) 34 12 84` Is that the expected? See https://regex101.com/r/ij49Hv/1

Comment: yeah you are right, it should match

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
\(?\+|0{0,2}\(?49\)?[ ()]*[ \d]+[ ()]*[ -]*\d{2}[ -]*\d{2}[ -]*\d{2}
```

https://regex101.com/r/CHjNBV/1

However, it's better to make it accept only `+49` or `0049`, and throw the error message in case the number fails validation. Because if someday you will require to extend the format - it will require making the regex much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the variations in the question, you might use a pattern like:

```
^(?:\+?(?:00)?(?:49|\(49\))|\(\+49\))(?: *\(\d{4}\)|(?: ?\d){4})? *\d\d(?:[ -]?\d\d){2}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\+?` Match an optional `+`
  - `(?:00)?` Optionally match 2 zeroes
  - `(?:49|\(49\))` Match 49 or `(49)`
  - `|` Or
  - `\(\+49\)` Match `(+49)`
- `)` Close non capture gruop
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `*` Match optional spaces
  - `\(\d{4}\)` Match `(` 4 digits and `)`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?: ?\d){4}` Repeat 4 times matching an optional space and a digit
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `*` Match optional spaces
- `\d\d` Match 2 digits
- `(?:[ -]?\d\d){2}` Repeat 2 times matching either a space or `-` followed by 2 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rvdaj2/1)

Or a bit broader variation matching the `49` prefix variants, followed by matching 10 digits allowing optional repetitions of what is in the character class `[ ()-]*` in between the digits.

```
^(?:\+?(?:00)?(?:49|\(49\))|\(\+49\))(?:[ ()-]*\d){10}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VTkDNi/1)